# i18next::backendConnector: loading namespace translation for language en failed TypeError

Tags: next.js, i18next

While trying to `run build` the project with i18next, I have following error.

```
i18next::backendConnector: loading namespace translation for language en failed TypeError: Only absolute URLs are supported
```

The `next-i18next.config` file contains the following code:

```
const path = require("path");

/** @type import("next").I18NConfig */
const i18n = {
    defaultLocale: 'en',
    locales: ['en', 'fr'],
    localeDetection: false // disable automatic redirection on the user's preferred locale
};

/** @type import("next-i18next").UserConfig */
const next18nextConfig = {
    i18n,
    fallbackLng: 'en',
    keySeparator: ".",
    nsSeparator: ":",
    localePath: path.resolve("./public/locales"),
    ns: ['common']
    // reloadOnPrerender: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development"
};
```

Translations are placed in:

```
/public/locales/[folder]/[file_name.json]
```

Example:

```
/public/locales/en/common.json
```

[Code](https://github.com/i18next/next-i18next/blob/master/examples/simple/next-i18next.config.js) I have tried (but not working also, same error).

*How to resolve this?*

Comment: I can understand this "[folder]", but "[translation_name.json]" looks strange to me

Comment: Maybe you need to take a look at this README section: typeof window === 'undefined'
      ? require('path').resolve('./my-custom/path')
      : '/public/my-custom/path'

`typeof window === 'undefined'
      ? require('path').resolve('./my-custom/path')
      : '/public/my-custom/path'`

Comment: Could you share the code of your project on GitHub? (Or at least a minimal reproducable example)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you're trying to load the translations via http also on server side.
If so, check [this](https://github.com/i18next/i18next-http-backend/tree/master/example/next) and make sure you pass the loadPath for the server side  with appropriate "http://" url or if you don't want to load translations via http-backend on server side, make sure you correctly configure the use option or the backends option.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you:

```
const path = require("path");

/** @type import("next").I18NConfig */
const i18n = {
    defaultLocale: 'en',
    locales: ['en', 'fr'],
    localeDetection: false // disable automatic redirection on the user's preferred locale
};

/** @type import("next-i18next").UserConfig */
const next18nextConfig = {
    i18n,
    fallbackLng: 'en',
    keySeparator: ".",
    nsSeparator: ":",
    localePath: typeof window === 'undefined'
  ? require('path').resolve("./locales") : '/public/locales',
    ns: ['common']
    // reloadOnPrerender: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development"
};
```

Comment: Try to experiment with resolving the path in this way

Comment: Same error, unfortunately

Comment: providing a complete example may help... because the provided example here seems to work: https://github.com/i18next/next-i18next/tree/master/examples/simple

Comment: @illiachill, then you can try console.logging this `typeof window === 'undefined'
  ? require('path').resolve("./locales") : '/public/locales'` in the same i18next config file, but before the next18nextConfig variable initialization, and see if the path you get is a valid path and you can reach the folder